# Using mysql query as a condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in a mySQL database where i put a value retrieved from an android application using php.
Now the value is a UniqueID,so i am keeping a count of it,so that i can know how many times my application is accessed.
When a new UniqueID arrives it is added to the database with count=1 and when an existing UniqueID is retieved,its count is simply incremented.
I tried my php script multiple times but with no luck. I am attaching my php script for reference.

```
<?php


ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$n=$_POST['UniqueID'];  
$count=1;  
$Today=date("F j, Y, g:i a");

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
mysql_select_db("farm-o-pedia");

$con="select userid from uniqueid";  
$result=mysql_query($con) or die(mysql_error());  
if($result=$n)  
{  

$upd="update uniqueid set count=count+1 where userid=$n";  
$result=mysql_query($upd) or die(mysql_error());  
}  
else  {  
$que="insert into uniqueid (userid,count,date) values($n,\"$count\",\"$Today\")";    
$sql=mysql_query($que) or die(mysql_error());  
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: The condition `$result=$n` may not work because i have no idea whether a query can be used for condition. Maybe i have to convert the query into an array or an object.

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated.

Comment: @lc:it maybe but it works for me here i don't know much about mysqli or PDO so tell me if u can find my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_query returns a **resultset**, not a single result, so:

```
$con="select userid from uniqueid";  
$result=mysql_query($con) or die(mysql_error());  
if($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { //if a row is found in resultset, then you already have this id in your table
    $upd="update uniqueid set count=count+1 where userid=$n";  
    $result=mysql_query($upd) or die(mysql_error());  
} else {  
    $que="insert into uniqueid (userid,count,date) values($n,\"$count\",\"$Today\")";    
    $sql=mysql_query($que) or die(mysql_error());  
}
```

Also you should start using mysqli functions instead of mysql, as mysql ones are deprecated

Comment: Thanks @Harlandraka, your answer was much helpful.It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this is by taking advantage of MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

The first thing to do is to define a `UNIQUE` constraint on column `userid` (*if it is PRIMARY KEY then skip this step.*),

```
ALTER TABLE uniqueid ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (userid)
```

After the query has been executed, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will work just fine now.

You will have no `SELECT` and other `IF`s on this.

```
INSERT INTO UNIQUEID (userID `count`, date)
VALUES ('idHere', 0, NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1;
```

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the line `if($result=$n)` - this will never work. Partly the comparison operator is `==` not `=` also the result string consists of a query result not a single value.

Replace the line with:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)===1)
```

Secondly you should really look into escaping your query and preferrably change from using deprecated mysql_* functions into PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Thanks @jtheman,this answer works too. So there are two ways for my question.

Comment: You have to choose just 1 answer as your preferred one... :)

Comment: both work for me but here it allows me only one to mark as the correct answer.

Comment: I agree Harlandraka's answer is more elaborate and also solves the question of incrementing count. However still you should escape the query, I think.